# How do you not show the WordPress plugins directory path in the browser?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say you have a plugin shortcode that generates a form in your post/page, and that form's action attribute is set to a script located in the same plugins directory as the shortcode that generated the form. How do you make it so WP does not expose the path to the plugins directory when it submits the form?

Basically, I want `domain.com/wp-install-dir/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/process_form.php` to map to `domain.com/plugin-name/process_form.php`, so that the `wp-install-dir/wp-content/plugins` part of the url path isn't exposed to the user.

Is there a WordPress way of specifying a path to a script in the plugins directory that does not expose the location of the plugins directory in the browser, or is this something I have to set up with `.htaccess`/`mod_rewrite`? I hope I'm asking my question clearly.

Comment: Dear Rylie, this is not a formal letter you have mailed to someone, it's a question you asked on the open internet.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm not being literal. I'm addressing this question to the general "WordPress plugin developer expert" public, not any one specific person. This lets people know the nature of my question, and the nature of the developer who might be able to help answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite

Working with the rewrite/routing system is about as advanced as it gets for a WordPress plugin developer. You should be a competent programmer and comfortable reading others' code and debugging your own.